# convert the output to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Following output need to be printed in dictionary

```
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Po1, Eth1/1, Eth1/2, Eth1/3
                                                Eth1/4, Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/7
                                                Eth1/8, Eth1/9, Eth1/10, Eth1/11
                                                Eth1/12, Eth1/13, Eth1/14
                                                Eth1/15, Eth1/16, Eth1/17
                                                Eth1/18, Eth1/19, Eth1/20
                                                Eth1/21, Eth1/22, Eth1/23
                                                Eth1/24, Eth1/25, Eth1/26
                                                Eth1/27, Eth1/28, Eth1/29
                                                Eth1/30, Eth1/31, Eth1/32
                                                Eth1/33, Eth1/34, Eth1/35
                                                Eth1/36, Eth1/38, Eth1/39
                                                Eth1/40, Eth1/41, Eth1/42
                                                Eth1/43, Eth1/44, Eth1/45
                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48
10   test                             active    Po1, Eth1/37, Eth1/41, Eth1/42
                                                Eth1/43, Eth1/44, Eth1/45
                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48
```

Required output:

```
[{'vlan_id': '1', 'name': 'default', 'status': 'active', 'interfaces': ['Po1', 'Po525', 'Eth1/33', 'Eth1/34', 'Eth1/35', 'Eth1/36', 'Eth1/38', 'Eth1/45', 'Eth1/46', 'Eth1/47', 'Eth1/48', 'Eth1/49', 'Eth1/50', 'Eth1/51', 'Eth1/52', 'Eth2/2', 'Eth2/21', 'Eth2/22', 'Eth2/23', 'Eth2/24', 'Eth2/25', 'Eth2/26', 'Eth3/1', 'Eth3/2', 'Eth3/3', 'Eth3/4', 'Eth3/7', 'Eth3/8', 'Eth3/9', 'Eth3/10', 'Eth3/11', 'Eth3/12', 'Eth3/13', 'Eth3/14', 'Eth3/15', 'Eth3/16', 'Eth3/17', 'Eth3/18', 'Eth3/19', 'Eth3/20', 'Eth3/21', 'Eth3/22', 'Eth3/23', 'Eth3/24', 'Eth3/25', 'Eth3/26']}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what part of that are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import ntc_templates
from ntc_templates.parse import parse_output

vlan_output = (
"VLAN Name                             Status    Ports\n"
"---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------\n"
"1    default                          active    Po1, Eth1/1, Eth1/2, Eth1/3\n"
"                                                Eth1/4, Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/7\n"
"                                                Eth1/8, Eth1/9, Eth1/10, Eth1/11\n"
"                                                Eth1/12, Eth1/13, Eth1/14\n"
"                                                Eth1/15, Eth1/16, Eth1/17\n"
"                                                Eth1/18, Eth1/19, Eth1/20\n"
"                                                Eth1/21, Eth1/22, Eth1/23\n"
"                                                Eth1/24, Eth1/25, Eth1/26\n"
"                                                Eth1/27, Eth1/28, Eth1/29\n"
"                                                Eth1/30, Eth1/31, Eth1/32\n"
"                                                Eth1/33, Eth1/34, Eth1/35\n"
"                                                Eth1/36, Eth1/38, Eth1/39\n"
"                                                Eth1/40, Eth1/41, Eth1/42\n"
"                                                Eth1/43, Eth1/44, Eth1/45\n"
"                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48\n"
"10   test                             active    Po1, Eth1/37, Eth1/41, Eth1/42\n"
"                                                Eth1/43, Eth1/44, Eth1/45\n"
"                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48\n")

vlan_parsed = parse_output(platform="cisco_ios", command="show vlan", data=vlan_output)
print(vlan_parsed)
```

It will return a dict like this :

```
[{'vlan_id': '1', 'name': 'default', 'status': 'active', 'interfaces': ['Po1', 'Eth1/1', 'Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth1/4', 'Eth1/5', 'Eth1/6', 'Eth1/7', 'Eth1/8', 'Eth1/9', 'Eth1/10', 'Eth1/11', 'Eth1/12', 'Eth1/13', 'Eth1/14', 'Eth1/15', 'Eth1/16', 'Eth1/17', 'Eth1/18', 'Eth1/19', 'Eth1/20', 'Eth1/21', 'Eth1/22', 'Eth1/23', 'Eth1/24', 'Eth1/25', 'Eth1/26', 'Eth1/27', 'Eth1/28', 'Eth1/29', 'Eth1/30', 'Eth1/31', 'Eth1/32', 'Eth1/33', 'Eth1/34', 'Eth1/35', 'Eth1/36', 'Eth1/38', 'Eth1/39', 'Eth1/40', 'Eth1/41', 'Eth1/42', 'Eth1/43', 'Eth1/44', 'Eth1/45', 'Eth1/46', 'Eth1/47', 'Eth1/48']}, {'vlan_id': '10', 'name': 'test', 'status': 'active', 'interfaces': ['Po1', 'Eth1/37', 'Eth1/41', 'Eth1/42', 'Eth1/43', 'Eth1/44', 'Eth1/45', 'Eth1/46', 'Eth1/47', 'Eth1/48']}]
```

Be careful when you install ntc_templates (for example with pip install ntc_templates).

It will use textfsm module, which can already be installed.
If you encounter :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clitable'
```

Just run :

```
pip install --upgrade textfsm==0.4.1
```

And run the script again

Comment: i had used it but i want to know other option with out installing ntc templates due to security.

Comment: thanks for the: pip install --upgrade textfsm==0.4.1 i was going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Add commas between values in your data, thus making a csv file.  Then follow instructions in the top of the following web article on csv (and excel) conversion to JSON. Your output desired is in JSON format.

---

https://medium.com/coinmonks/parsing-a-spreadsheet-into-a-json-file-using-python-6118f5c70bd3

---

start at line with

---

import csv, json

Answer (score 0):

It involves a lot of parsing. I hope below snippet helps in doing so

```
s = """VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Po1, Eth1/1, Eth1/2, Eth1/3
                                                Eth1/4, Eth1/5, Eth1/6, Eth1/7
                                                Eth1/8, Eth1/9, Eth1/10, Eth1/11
                                                Eth1/12, Eth1/13, Eth1/14
                                                Eth1/15, Eth1/16, Eth1/17
                                                Eth1/18, Eth1/19, Eth1/20
                                                Eth1/21, Eth1/22, Eth1/23
                                                Eth1/24, Eth1/25, Eth1/26
                                                Eth1/27, Eth1/28, Eth1/29
                                                Eth1/30, Eth1/31, Eth1/32
                                                Eth1/33, Eth1/34, Eth1/35
                                                Eth1/36, Eth1/38, Eth1/39
                                                Eth1/40, Eth1/41, Eth1/42
                                                Eth1/43, Eth1/44, Eth1/45
                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48
10   test                             active    Po1, Eth1/37, Eth1/41, Eth1/42
                                                Eth1/43, Eth1/44, Eth1/45
                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48"""

new_line_split = s.split("\n")
headers = list(filter(None, new_line_split[0].split(" ")))
print(headers)
sessions_data = []
ports = []
session = {}
for line in new_line_split[2:]:
    values = list(filter(None,line.split(" ")))

    for index, value in enumerate(values):
        if value.startswith("Eth", 0) or value.startswith("Po", 0):
            ports.append(value.strip(","))
            session[headers[3]] = ports
        elif index in [0,1,2]:

            if index == 0:
                session = {}
                ports = []
            elif bool(session):
                sessions_data.append(session)
            session[headers[index]] = value

print(sessions_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

textfsm template code:

```
Value vlan_id (\d+)
Value name (\w+)
Value status (\S+)
Value List interfaces ([\w/]+)

Start
  ^\d+ -> Continue.Record
  ^${vlan_id}\s+${name}\s+${status}\s*$$
  ^${vlan_id}\s+${name}\s+${status}\s+${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\d+\s+(\S+\s+){3}${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\d+\s+(\S+\s+){4}${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\d+\s+(\S+\s+){5}${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\s+(\S+\s+){0}${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\s+(\S+\s+){1}${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\s+(\S+\s+){2}${interfaces},* -> Continue
  ^\s+(\S+\s+){3}${interfaces},* -> Continue
```

output screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb8fA.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to just extract the values with regex and populate the list.  Note: I just copied the contents of your network gear text into /tmp/whatever.file.

```
import re

rx = "^(?P<vlan>\d+)\s+(?P<vlanname>\w+)\s+(?P<status>\w+)(?P<ports>[\s\S]*)(?=\n\d+)$"

with open("/tmp/whatever.file") as f:
    content = f.read()

result = re.findall(rx, content, re.MULTILINE)

lst = []
for r in result:
    vlan, vlanname, status, ports = r
    lst.append({
        "vlan_id": vlan,
        "name": vlanname,
        "status": status,
        "ports": [x for x in ports.replace("\n", ",").replace(" ", "").split(",")]
    })
print(lst)
```